# Frisbyにおける非同期処理の順序制御に関して

Tags: 非同期, jasmine

Frisbyに関して、以下の動作を期待しています。

①動作A
②動作B
③動作C

1. ①動作Aおよび②動作Bを非同期で実施する。
   （それぞれ複雑なDB操作を行いますが、衝突はしません。）
2. 【1.】が実施され、完了後に③動作Cを実施し、APIのテストを行う。

Localで実行したところ、現時点では【1.】と【2.】の制御が上手くいっておりません。
アドバイス・知見等をご教示頂きたいです。

> describe('test', (done) => {
>   //////////////////////////////////////////////
>     var originalTimeout;
>
> beforeEach((done) => { 
>         console.log('★★★★★before_proceed');
>
> ```
>   // 動作A
>
>   // 動作B
> ```
>
> });
>
> it('試験実施:', (done) => {
>         // 動作C
>
> });
>   });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promise.all を使った並列化が可能であると考えられます。

コード:

```
const frisby = require('frisby');

describe('test', () => {

  beforeEach((done) => { 
    console.log('★★★★★before_proceed');
    Promise.all([

      // 動作A
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => console.log("A start"))
        .then(() => frisby.get('https://www.google.com').expect('status', 200))
        .then(() => console.log("A end")),

      // 動作B 失敗するように書きます
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => console.log("B start"))
        .then(() => frisby.get('https://www.google.com').expect('status', 400))
        .then(() => console.log("B end"))

    ]).then(done).catch(done);
  });

  it('試験実施:', (done) => {
    // 動作C
    expect(1).toBe(1);
    done();
  });

});
```

出力:

```
Randomized with seed 83497
Started
★★★★★before_proceed
A start
B start
A end
F

Failures:
1) test 試験実施:
  Message:
    Failed: HTTP status 400 !== 200
  Stack:
    error properties: Object({ generatedMessage: false, code: 'ERR_ASSERTION', actual: 200, expected: 400, operator: '===' })
        at <Jasmine>
        at FrisbySpec.status (/Users/set0gut1/tmp/g/node_modules/frisby/src/frisby/expects.js:25:12)
        at response (/Users/set0gut1/tmp/g/node_modules/frisby/src/frisby/spec.js:373:23)
        at _fetch._fetch.then.response (/Users/set0gut1/tmp/g/node_modules/frisby/src/frisby/spec.js:214:34)
        at <Jasmine>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.197 seconds
Randomized with seed 83497 (jasmine --random=true --seed=83497)
```